# Alternative proof of the "Recursion Theorem" from Enderton's A Mathematical Introduction To Logic?

Tags: logic

In *A Mathematical Introduction To Logic* Chapter 1, Enderton states and proves a recursion theorem:

> Suppose a subset $C$ of $U$ is *freely generated* from a subset $B$ of
>   $U$ by functions $f:U\times U \rightarrow U$ and $g:U \rightarrow U$,
>   $h:B \rightarrow V$ is a function, $F:V \times V \rightarrow V$ is a
>   function, and $G: V \rightarrow V$ is a function.   Then there is an
>   extension $\overline{h}:C \rightarrow V$ which is compatible with $f$,
>   $g$, $F$, and $G$ in the sense that
>
> a) $F(\overline{h}(x), \overline{h}(y)) = \overline{h}(f(x, y))$   b)
>   $G(\overline{h}(x)) = \overline{h}(g(x))$

His proof is a "top-down" proof in the sense that he looks at the union $u$ of a certain collection of admissible extensions $v$ of $h$ to subsets of $C$, shows $u$ is a function, and that the domain of $u$ is an inductive subset of $C$, and so is $C$ itself.

He is working with $C = C^*$, the "top-down" description of $C$ as the smallest inductive set relative to $B$, $f$, and $g$.

I thought it was a cool proof, but was not the one I came up with when I tried to figure it out for myself.

The idea that I had was more of a "bottom-up" approach, where you use the decomposition
$$C = C* = \overset{\circ}{\bigcup} _k C_k$$ 
$C_k$ is the collection of elements in $C$ which have $k$ as a shortest length for a construction sequence.
It seems intuitive to extend $h$ from $B = C_1$ to $C_2$, $C_3$, $\dots$ using ordinary induction, $F$, $G$, and the unique decomposition of $x \in C_k$ afforded by $C$ being freely generated.
Take the disjoint union of these extensions as $\overline{h}$.

The trouble is that I'm worried I'm cheating, *in Enderton's setting*.
On the one hand it feels like I'm just begging the question.
On the other had, he has invoked ordinary induction earlier in the book, and has explicitly said it's set in informal mathematics and not axiomatic set theory.

Maybe induction using something like the following predicate might work?

> There is a unique extension of $h$ to $$D_k = \overset{\circ}{\bigcup}_{j=1}^k C_j$$ satisfying a) whenever $f(x,y)$ is in $D_k$, and satisfying b) whenever $g(x)$ is in $D_k$.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which edition are you using? I am looking at 2nd edition pdf.

Comment: In 2nd on page 40 there is Example 1. I was trying to make sense of it. It would be helpful if you applied Enderton's proof to build up the functions on that example, and then tried your approach. It looks like he replaces $V \times V$ with $\mathbb N$ but I'm new to this material and getting lost.

Comment: Yes, 2nd edition

Comment: My guess is that for your idea to work, you will wind up having to do the same thing Enderton does in his proof. Namely, since you have only 'fragments', you will have to explain why the union of the graphs (direct limit) is a function, that it is uniquely satisfies the recursion scheme.

Comment: But if you take Enderton's proof (and existence and uniqueness of $\bar h$)  as a given, you are certainly justified in building the function from the bottom up, and if you can 'get up to' $C$ be satisfied that you have the 'real deal'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can always replace the "top down" construction of $h$ with a "bottom up" construction. The key is finding the right inductive hypothesis for the bottom-up version.

In this case, rather than looking at construction sequences, I would look at construction trees. I would first prove that each element of $C$ has a unique construction tree (that is, a unique parse tree in the sense of computer science).  This does require using the inductive definition of $C$, so it will still look like a top-down proof, unavoidably.

Then I would construct $h$ by induction on the height of the construction tree. In other words, we define $h$ simultaneously for all trees of height $0$, then for all trees of height $1$, and so on. This will no longer require the definition of $C$ - we are defining $h$ on *every* construction tree, it just happens to be that the set of expressions that have construction trees is $C$.

Note that sections 1.3 and 2.3 are included to solve the opposite question. It is easy to show that every element of $C$ has a construction tree. Those sections show that this tree can be algorithmically recovered by parsing an expression.

Comment: I think, however, that I'll stick with construction sequences. Enderton explicitly says (2nd Ed. p. 7) that trees are used only informally in the book. Minimal length construction sequences for a freely generated set should suffice.